# amcharts4 bullets out of alignment

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts4

The bullets on my amchart4 chart are not on the line. Why are they out of alignment? How can I put them on the line? the code does not seem to have an option to realign? there are no obvious errors in the code? unless this is being caused from css or other code on website?

[image: screenshot]

```js
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

   
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
var chart = am4core.createFromConfig({
 "data": <?php echo $a?>
}, "chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "balance_amount";
series.dataFields.dateX = "balance_date";
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
bullet.circle.radius = 4;
bullet.circle.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
var bullethover = bullet.states.create("hover");
bullethover.properties.scale = 1.3;
var range = valueAxis.createSeriesRange(series);
range.value = 0;
range.endValue = -1000;
range.contents.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(4);
range.contents.fill = range.contents.stroke;
range.contents.strokeOpacity = 0.7;
range.contents.fillOpacity = 0.1;
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "panXY";
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;
 series.strokeWidth = 3; // 3px
 series.tensionX = 0.8;
series.tensionY = 0.8;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
chart.events.on("ready", function () {
  dateAxis.zoom({start:0, end:1});   
});

}); // end am4core.ready()
</script>
```